# Performance issue in PDFBox load function

Tags: java, performance, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox 2.0.24 and JAVA 8 to load pdf file. It takes around 53 mins to load 9 page PDF file. Code snippet is as below:

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\local\first.pdf"), MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
```

We load pdf to check file is password protected or not? Can someone suggest any optimize way or other approach for this.

Comment: Don't use the second parameter and update to 2.0.27.

Comment: Also *"9 page PDF"* doesn't mean anything. A PDF of 9 pages may contain more complicated structure and huger resources than another 1000 page PDF.